# Retrieving sql errors from sqlcmd.exe with output option

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, error-handling, sqlcommand, sqlcmd

I have a process running in C# on a windows service that executes a sql commmand. This in turn executes a sproc to populate a csv file. Currently if this sproc errors it outputs the error to the csv file, but I need to be able to access this error from my C# code and handle it accordingly.

```
public static void RunAndWaitForProgram(string executablePath, string arguments)
    {
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(executablePath, arguments);

        var processToRun = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = startInfo
        };

        processToRun.Start();
        processToRun.WaitForExit();
    }
```

(Where executablePath is the path to sqlcmd and arguments the command I wish to run)

I'm completely new to sqlcmd and this implementation is required due to legacy constraints.

I've looked into using sqlcmd operation -r (see below) to no avail and my last resort is to scan the csv with a regex to pick up any errors each time the sproc runs. Is there anyway I can avoid this?

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe" -S database\content -Q "EXEC sproc @variable = '1'" -o "C:\folderpath\data.csv" -f 65001 -W -X -r1 -s"±" -v Variable="4"
```

Comment: Why do you need `sqlcmd` at all? Why don't just execute sql commands from C# code itself using `SqlCommand` class?

Comment: Unfortunately it's legacy and we are restricted to using sqlcmd.exe - else I would have liked to have gone down the suggested route.